# alter Dijkstra's Algorithm to compute shortest second and third path between two nodes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

how to alter Dijkstra's Algorithm in [link](http://hansolav.net/sql/graphs.html#dijkstra) to calculate shortest second and third path between two nodes?

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far? Please see [how to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MegaTron i'm Novice in sql

Answer (score 0):

Dijkstra’s shortest path algorithm is a greedy algorithm. This means that at any given point, Dijkstra has found the shortest path from its start up to the current vertex that it is at. Dijkstra’s shortest path algorithm has optimal substructure, because the optimal solution relies on the optimal solution of the subproblems.

Say you are trying to find the shortest path from node **A** to node **B**. Dijkstra works by keeping track of the shortest path from **A** up to the current node that it is at, up until the algorithm completes the path to **B**. The algorithm does not keep track of the second or third best paths, as it is a greedy algorithm with optimal substructure.

If you want to find the second or third shortest path between **A** and **B**, you cannot just perform Dijkstra’s algorithm and rely on it only needing to make one different decision along the way. You may need to go through many, or even all, paths that connect **A** and **B**, to find the next shortest paths.

In a very large graph, we would need to keep track of many nodes and possible paths before finding the second or third shortest paths. Finding the nth shortest path does not follow the property of a greedy algorithm with optimal substructure.